# jQuery .load() get content without append

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, css

I was wondering hwo to make function .load() without append in some selector

For example I'd like to get variables as array from another file which I did thanks to script below.
But I have to append it on #selector to retrieve information I want to get.
Is there any way to get those information without creating this selector.
Of course i can "display: none;" this selector. But I would like to have clean code.

Any ideas would be appreciate :))

```
$("#selector").load('content/file.php', function (result) {
    var hrefs = new Array();
    $("ul li").each(function () {
        hrefs.push($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to fetch the contents from the said resource then find the `ul li` elements like

```
$.get('content/file.php', function (result) {
    var hrefs = $(result).find("ul li").map(function () {
        return $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    }).get();
}, 'html');
```

---

No need to use `.find()` to find the anchor elements, add it to the `ul li` selector

```
$.get('content/file.php', function (result) {
    var hrefs = $(result).find("ul li a").map(function () {
        return $(this).attr('href');
    }).get();
}, 'html');
```

Answer (score 1):

try ajax call

```
var response;
$.ajax({ type: "GET",   
     url: 'content/file.php',
     async: false,
     success : function(text)
     {
          var hrefs = $(text).find("ul li").map(function () {
    return $(this).find('a').attr('href');
}).get();
     }
});
```

Comment: I can't use this beacuase this script is inside another getjson script.

Comment: that's correct too, thank you very much, and appreciate for you time. But @Arun P Johny was first givin me first correct anwser. Still gave you "this anwser is usefull" thank you :)